# Using Comparable<T> with Generic class

Tags: java, generics

A newbie question (possibly duplicate too) but can someone point me what's wrong with the below code:

```
public class Node<T> implements Comparable<Node<T>> {

    protected final Comparable<T> data;
    protected final List<Node<T>> adj;

    public Node(Comparable<T> data) {
        this.data = data;
        adj = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node<T> other) {
        return data.compareTo(other.data);
    }
}
```

The compareTo method shows a compilation error: 
compareTo(T) in Comparable cannot be applied to (java.lang.Comparable).

Alternatively I tried using `public class Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>>` but then if I add this `Node` in, say, an ArrayList> then I am not able to use the `contains` method of ArrayList.
I'd be very thankful if someone points me out the difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to tell Java that `T` extends `Comparable<T>`, like this:

```
public static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Comparable<Node<T>> {

    protected final T data;
    protected final List<Node<T>> adj;

    public Node(T data) {
        this.data = data;
        adj = new ArrayList<Node<T>>();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Node<T> other) {
        return data.compareTo(other.data);
    }
}
```

`Comparable<T>` says that you can apply `compareTo` method to an object of type `T`. When your version declared

```
Comparable<T> data
```

and then tried to compare `data` to `Comparable<T>` instead of `T`, the compiler objected, because `T` and `Comparable<T>` are incompatible.

**NOTE:** For greater flexibility, use `Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>>`. This would let you mix and match nodes based on different subclasses in the same comparison (thanks, [JB Nizet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/571407/jb-nizet), for a great suggestion).

Comment: Agreed. I would use `Node<T extends Comparable<? super T>>` though.

Comment: Yes, I tried the suggestion and it works nicely, although I was interested to know if I do `Comparable<T> data` instead of 'T data' then why does compiler throw error when I do `overridden compareTo(<Node<T> other) { data.compareTo(other.data); }`

Comment: Ah, got it. Posted my comment before seeing the edit.